# Boost synchronization

Tags: c++, multithreading, boost-thread

I have NUM_THREADS threads, with the following codes in my thread:

```
/*
Calculate some_value;
*/

//Critical section to accummulate all thresholds
{
    boost::mutex::scoped_lock lock(write_mutex);
    T += some_value;
    num_threads++;
    if (num_threads == NUM_THREADS){
        T = T/NUM_THREADS;
        READY = true;
        cond.notify_all();
        num_threads = 0;
    }
}

//Wait for average threshold to be ready
if (!READY)
{
    boost::unique_lock<boost::mutex> lock(wait_mutex);
    while (!READY){
        cond.wait(lock);
    }
}
//End critical section

/*
do_something;
*/
```

Basically, I want all the threads to wait for the READY signal before continuing. num_thread is set to 0, and READY is false before threads are created. Once in a while, deadlock occurs. Can anyone help please?
All the boost variables are globally declared  as follows:

```
boost::mutex write_mutex;
boost::mutex wait_mutex;
boost::condition cond;
```

Comment: What sets `READY` back to `false`? Or do you mean in some runs it deadlocks and in some runs it works fine?

Comment: READY is set to false when all threads finish. Yes, most of the time it works fine, except for deadlock once in a while. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code has a race condition on the `READY` flag (which I assume is just a `bool` variable). What may happen (i.e. one possible variant of thread execution interleaving) is:

```
Thread T1:                                 Thread T2:
if (!READY)                                
{
    unique_lock<mutex> lock(wait_mutex);   mutex::scoped_lock lock(write_mutex);
    while (!READY)                         /* ... */
    {                                      READY = true;
        /* !!! */                          cond.notify_all();
        cond.wait(lock);
    }
}
```

The code testing the `READY` flag is not synchronized with the code setting it (note the locks are different for these critical sections). And when T1 is in a "hole" between the flag test and waiting at `cond`, T2 may set the flag and send a signal to `cond` which T1 may miss.

The simplest solution is to lock the right mutex for the update of `READY` and condition notification:

```
/*...*/
T = T/NUM_THREADS;
{
    boost::mutex::scoped_lock lock(wait_mutex);
    READY = true;
    cond.notify_all();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like Boost.Thread's [barriers](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/doc/html/thread/synchronization.html#thread.synchronization.barriers) might be what you need.

Here's a working example that averages values provided by several worker threads. Each worker thread uses the same shared barrier (via the `accumulator` instance) to synchronize each other.

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <boost/bind.hpp>
#include <boost/shared_ptr.hpp>
#include <boost/thread.hpp>

boost::mutex coutMutex;
typedef boost::lock_guard<boost::mutex> LockType;

class Accumulator
{
public:
    Accumulator(int count) : barrier_(count), sum_(0), count_(count) {}

    void accumulateAndWait(float value)
    {
        {
            // Increment value
            LockType lock(mutex_);
            sum_ += value;
        }
        barrier_.wait(); // Wait for other the threads to wait on barrier.
    }

    void wait() {barrier_.wait();} // Wait on barrier without changing sum.

    float sum() {LockType lock(mutex_); return sum_;} // Return current sum

    float average() {LockType lock(mutex_); return sum_ / count_;}

    // Reset the sum. The barrier is automatically reset when triggered.
    void reset() {LockType lock(mutex_); sum_ = 0;}

private:
    typedef boost::lock_guard<boost::mutex> LockType;
    boost::barrier barrier_;
    boost::mutex mutex_;
    float sum_;
    int count_;
};

/*  Posts a value for the accumulator to add and waits for other threads
    to do the same. */
void workerFunction(Accumulator& accumulator)
{
    // Sleep for a random amount of time before posting value
    int randomMilliseconds = std::rand() % 3000;
    boost::posix_time::time_duration randomDelay =
            boost::posix_time::milliseconds(randomMilliseconds);
    boost::this_thread::sleep(randomDelay);

    // Post some random value
    float value = std::rand() % 100;

    {
        LockType lock(coutMutex);
        std::cout << "Thread " << boost::this_thread::get_id() << " posting "
                  << value << " after " << randomMilliseconds << "ms\n";
    }
    accumulator.accumulateAndWait(value);

    float avg = accumulator.average();

    // Print a message to indicate this thread is past the barrier.
    {
        LockType lock(coutMutex);
        std::cout << "Thread " << boost::this_thread::get_id() << " unblocked. "
                  << "Average = " << avg << "\n" << std::flush;
    }
}

int main()
{
    int workerThreadCount = 5;
    Accumulator accumulator(workerThreadCount);

    // Create and launch worker threads
    boost::thread_group threadGroup;
    for (int i=0; i<workerThreadCount; ++i)
    {
        threadGroup.create_thread(
                boost::bind(&workerFunction, boost::ref(accumulator)));
    }

    // Wait for all worker threads to finish
    threadGroup.join_all();
    {
        LockType lock(coutMutex);
        std::cout << "All worker threads finished\n" << std::flush;
    }

    /* Pause a bit before exiting, to give worker threads a chance to
       print their messages. */
    boost::this_thread::sleep(boost::posix_time::seconds(1));
}
```

I get the following output:

```
Thread 0x100100f80 posting 72 after 1073ms
Thread 0x100100d30 posting 44 after 1249ms
Thread 0x1001011d0 posting 78 after 1658ms
Thread 0x100100ae0 posting 23 after 1807ms
Thread 0x100101420 posting 9 after 1930ms
Thread 0x100101420 unblocked. Average = 45.2
Thread 0x100100f80 unblocked. Average = 45.2
Thread 0x100100d30 unblocked. Average = 45.2
Thread 0x1001011d0 unblocked. Average = 45.2
Thread 0x100100ae0 unblocked. Average = 45.2
All worker threads finished
```

Comment: Thanks! The problem here is that after the average is calculated, the threads go on to do something else. How can I do that?

Comment: Do the threads just keep producing the same type of values to average, over and over again, or do they do something else completely different? Anyhow, after sync'ing on the barrier, there's nothing to stop them from doing other their stuff in their respective thread functions.

Comment: The only problem is the remaining codes of the thread require the computed average to execute.

Comment: @Mickey: See updated answer. The main thread no longer waits on the barrier, and it's no longer the one that computes the average. This assumes that the average only needs to be computed once. I also now make use of `boost::thead_group`.