# boost::condition_variable and lock

Tags: c++, multithreading, boost

```
boost::condition_variable cond;
boost::mutex mut;

//thread1
{
"read_socket()"
cond.notify_one();
}

//thread2
{
for(;;)
{
...
boost::unique_lock<boost::mutex> lock(mut);
cond.wait(lock);
}
}
```

versus

```
boost::condition_variable cond;
boost::mutex mut;

//thread1
{
"read_socket()"
boost::unique_lock<boost::mutex> lock(mut);
cond.notify_one();
}

//thread2
{
for(;;)
{
...
boost::unique_lock<boost::mutex> lock(mut);
cond.wait(lock);
}
```

Is there an impact if I omit the lock before calling cond.notify_one() ?

Comment: `cond.wait(lock)` can resume before the call to `notify_one()`. You should always `wait` in a loop, testing the *condition* every time (or use the overload that takes a predicate).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The C++11 standard does not state any requirement for `notify_one` and `notify_all`; so not holding the lock when you signal a condition_variable is fine. However, it's often necessary for the signaling thread to hold the lock until it sets the condition checked by the waiting thread after it's woken up. If it does not, the program may contain races. For an example, see this SO question: [Boost synchronization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9014374/boost-synchronization).

Comment: However it seems that the lock use by the wait call is useless, as it is use only by wait

Answer (score 2):

When `thread2` is waking, it will attempt to re-aquire the lock. If `thread1` is holding the lock, `thread2` will block until `thread1` releases the lock.

In the code shown here, this doesn't significantly impact behavior. If you were to add any behavior in `thread1` after `cond.notify_one();`, that behavior would be guaranteed to execute before `thread2` proceeds in the second code block only.

Alternatively, you could construct the unique lock in `thread2` before entering the for loop, rather than just before waiting on the condition variable. This would ensure that `thread1` blocks when trying to construct its own unique lock until `thread2` is waiting for a signal, provided that `thread1` is not executing before `thread2` has initialized itself and entered the loop. This would allow you to guarantee that `thread1` doesn't send any notifications that `thread2` isn't waiting for.